# Guild Wars 2 cosmetic armor works only on one armor?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have bough Guild Wars 2 Heroic Edition and I have got that items, that can change the way that armor looks, I'm only level 10 and I'm not sure how does this armor works. So I'd like to ask if it's bounded on items that I use, that low level armors or can I remove it after I find better armor?

If my question isn't clear, here is an example, there are that https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVIHV.jpg apperance change items, if I use them now on low items, can I remove it afterward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The April 15, 2014 feature pack changed this functionality.

#### Since April 15, 2014:

- You have a "wardrobe" containing all skins you own. You'll be able to apply them to any number of items by using transmutation charges.
- Skins from all soul-bound and account-bound items you own are added to the wardrobe.
- An item's tooltip shows whether you have the item's skin "unlocked" or "locked".
- You can choose to unlock a locked skin by choosing "Unlock Skin" from the item's context menu.
- Salvaging, mystic forging or destroying an item unlocks the skin as well.
- See [this blog post](https://www.guildwars2.com/en/news/introducing-the-wardrobe-system) and the [wiki entry](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Wardrobe) for more information on the wardrobe.

#### Prior to April 15, 2014:

- "Skin" items like this could be applied once, for free, using up the item.
- The look of any item (including one with a "skin" applied to it) could be transferred to another item of the appropriate type by using transmutation stones or crystals.

Comment: Can't wait for Wardrobe! Squeeee

Comment: In addition to this, IIRC, you actually get 2 sets of armor/skins with the armor pack from the Heroic edition - a set of low(ish) level armor and also a set of skins you can apply to any armor. Not that this matters past tomorrow.